# How to prove these 2 theorems with the help of the function below?

Tags: coq

First, the function [foldc] should be defined, using the supplementary [eqfx].

```
Definition eq_corx {X : Type} (eqfx : X -> X -> bool) :=
  forall (x y : X), x = y <-> eqfx x y = true.

Definition foldc {X: Type} {eqfx} : @eq_corx X eqfx -> X -> list X ->  nat  :=
```

With [foldc], I would like to prove these 2 theorems below.

First:

```
Theorem foldc1  {X : Type} {eqfx} (eqx: eq_corx eqfx): 
  forall (l : list X),
    (forall (x:X), foldc eqfx x l = 0) <-> l = nil.
```

I tried to prove by induction on l, but I'm stuck.

Second:

```
Theorem foldc2 {X : Type} {eqfx} : 
    forall (l : list X) (eqx: eq_corx eqfx) (x y : X), 
    x = y <-> foldc eqx y (x::l)  = S (foldc eqx y l).
```

I tried unfolding [foldc], it didn't help unfortunately.

By the way, this is how [fold_right] is defined, which should help defining [foldc]:

```
Print fold_right.
fun (A B : Type) (f : B -> A -> A) (a0 : A) =>
fix fold_right (l : list B) : A :=
  match l with
  | [] => a0
  | b :: t => f b (fold_right t)
  end
     : forall A B : Type, (B -> A -> A) -> A -> list B -> A
```

Comment: Have you tried proving your theorems on paper? What makes you think they are true? As a hint: when unfolding `count_fold`, you get stuck on some `eqf x y`. In general, this does not help, but if you are stuck on `eqf x x` then by your hypothesis on `eqf`, this should be `true`, which would unblock the computation. Equivalently, try and prove what `count_fold eq x (x::l)` is equal to.

Comment: I reverted the question because it was a lot less clear than the original question. In particular, your edit lacked any context and left out the definition of eq_corx. I'm not sure why you felt you needed to rename things that way. Feel free to rename things but please try to not make things more confusing in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simplify a little your definition of `foldc` (removing the hypothesis of correctness of `eqfx`.

```
Definition foldc {X: Type} (eqfx: X -> X -> bool) :
  X -> list X ->  nat  :=
  fun  x l =>
    fold_right (fun y n => if eqfx x y then n + 1 else n) 0 l.
```

Then you can prove your first theorem by induction on `l`.
The only non-trivial subgoal which will appear will be of this form:

```
  l : list X
  IHl : (forall x : X, foldc eqfx x l = 0) <-> l = nil
  H : forall x : X, foldc eqfx x (a :: l) = 0
  ============================
  a :: l = nil
```

Obviously,  `H` will lead to a contradiction, when specialized to `a`.

```
Require Import Lia.

Theorem foldc1  {X : Type} {eqfx} (eqx: eq_corx eqfx): 
  forall (l : list X),
    (forall (x:X), foldc eqfx x l = 0) <-> l = nil.
  induction l.
  - split; trivial.
  -  split; [| discriminate].
     intro H.
     specialize (H a);  cbn in H; replace (eqfx a a) with true in H.
      exfalso;  lia.
      symmetry; red in eqx; now rewrite  <- eq.
Qed.
```